# How to group results of a postgres table if any of the fields match?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql table of records Where every every record has a record in that table that matches it on at least one of three possible fields.

```
id |   name   |       email       | phone | product
----------------------------------------------------
 1 |  Rob A   | foo@bar.com       | 123   | 102
 2 |  Rob B   | foo@bar.com       | 323   | 102
 3 |  Rob C   | foo@bcr.com       | 123   | 102
 4 |  Rob A   | foo@bdr.com       | 523   | 102
 5 |  Rob A   | foo@bar.com       | 123   | 104
 6 |  Cat A   | liz@bar.com       | 999   | 102
 7 |  Cat B   | lid@bar.com       | 999   | 102
 8 |  Cat A   | lib@bar.com       | 991   | 102
```

I want to group tables any tables where the "product" matches and **any** of these other three fields, (name, email, phone). So the groups would end up looking like

```
id |   name   |       email       | phone | product
----------------------------------------------------
 1 |  Rob A   | foo@bar.com       | 123   | 102
 2 |  Rob B   | foo@bar.com       | 323   | 102
 3 |  Rob C   | foo@bcr.com       | 123   | 102
 4 |  Rob A   | foo@bdr.com       | 523   | 102

 5 |  Rob A   | foo@bar.com       | 123   | 104

 6 |  Cat A   | liz@bar.com       | 999   | 102
 7 |  Cat B   | lid@bar.com       | 999   | 102
 8 |  Cat A   | lib@bar.com       | 991   | 102
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: table has five  columns which three is it matching on?  what rules are you using to make your example grouping?, what result do you want? do you need order by id ?

Comment: And why isn't "5" in the first group?

Comment: @Jasen I clarified which fields in the question. The second table isn't what the resultant rows should look like, but those are what should end up in the group. ordering isn't important, I will likely use this to reduce each group to a set of 1 id with a max(id) so the results would be 

4, 5, 8. The order does not matter

Comment: @GordonLinoff 5 isn't in the first group because it needs to match on "Product" AND on one of the other three fields

Comment: @PAndrews . . . It matches on *all three* of the fields.  That isn't sufficient?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no it **has** to match the product field *and* one of the other three. if it doesn't match the product field it is distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we `INNER JOIN` the table with itself like

```
SELECT t1.id id1,
       t2.id id2
       FROM elbat t1
            INNER JOIN elbat t2
                       ON t2.product = t1.product
                          AND (t2.name = t1.name
                                OR t2.email = t1.email
                                 OR t2.phone = t1.phone)
                          AND t2.id > t1.id;
```

we'll have the lowest ID of a "group" with more than one row in `id1`. For each `id1` the other members of the "group" are in `id2`.

That is, we can join the result from the query above, so that for each row the lowest ID of the "group" is joined. As rows, which build a "group" on their own or rows, which already have the lowest ID of a "group" won't find a partner row, we have to `LEFT JOIN`. We can now use the joined lowest ID, or the ID of a row itself, if there wasn't joined any partner row, as the "group" ID using `coalesce()`.

```
SELECT coalesce(x.id1, t.id) groupid,
       t.*
       FROM elbat t
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT t1.id id1,
                              t2.id id2
                              FROM elbat t1
                                   INNER JOIN elbat t2
                                              ON t2.product = t1.product
                                                 AND (t2.name = t1.name
                                                       OR t2.email = t1.email
                                                        OR t2.phone = t1.phone)
                                                 AND t2.id > t1.id) x
                      ON x.id2 = t.id
       ORDER BY coalesce(x.id1, t.id);
```

As we also ordered by the "group" ID, we can sequentially traverse the result in any application and know, if the "group" ID changes, we're reading the first row of a new "group".

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ac5214d137ef58fbe8aab6e774325b10)

Comment: This worked great, thank you. just note that in the first script there was an extra ')' leftover at the end

Comment: @PAndrews: Welcome. Ah yes, the `)` came from copying that part from the whole query. I corrected it.